# Excel VBA printing to PDF

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set the default printer when printing to PDF but getting the error "Method ActivePrinter of object _application failed"

```
Application.ActivePrinter = "Microsoft Print to PDF"
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
.PaperSize = xlPaperA4
End With

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
    "C:\Users\" & Environ$("UserName") & "\Downloads\" & Replace(Worksheets("test").Cells(1, 1), ".", "") & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

How can I set the printer to Microsoft Print to PDF?

Comment: Please try the next scenario. Manually print something in "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer. In Win 10 it will remain as ActivePrinter. Then try `Debug.Print Application.ActivePrinter`. It should return in `Immediate Window` something like `Microsoft Print to PDF on Ne..:` (port included). Then try using the returned string to set it as `ActivePrinter`.

Comment: @FaneDuru this returned "on Ne01" but it won't be "on Ne01" for other users of the file. Is it possible to not specify this part?

Comment: It is... I will post a complicated code which I have in my computer for some time. I am not his father.

Comment: @FaneDuru sorry, do you mean it will be Ne01 for everyone - if so how do you know?

Comment: I will post a code returning all installed printers and a function to extract the necessary one..

Comment: Take a look at this url https://vbaoverall.com/list-of-available-printers-in-windows-using-vba-code-example/ and you will find the exactly name of your Microsoft print to PDF.

Comment: Still alive? Did you try the code I posted? If tested, doesn't it work as you need?

Comment: ExportAsFixedFormat with xlTypePDF exports to PDF without bothering to change ActivePrinter. So why do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, copy the next function in a standard module:

```
Function FindPrinter(ByVal PrinterName As String) As String
  Dim arrH, Pr, Printers, Printer As String
  Dim RegObj As Object, RegValue As String
  Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
       
    Set RegObj = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
    RegObj.Enumvalues HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Devices", Printers, arrH
    
      For Each Pr In Printers
        RegObj.getstringvalue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Devices", Pr, RegValue
        Printer = Pr & " on " & Split(RegValue, ",")(1)
        If InStr(1, Printer, PrinterName, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
           FindPrinter = Printer
           Exit Function
        End If
      Next
End Function
```

And use it in this way:

```
Sub testFindPrinter()
    Debug.Print FindPrinter("Microsoft Print to PDF")
End Sub
```

Or for your specific case:

```
Application.ActivePrinter = FindPrinter("Microsoft Print to PDF")
```

Please, test it and send some feedback